# How can I rewrite this PHP function to extract data from an external website/source

Tags: php, xml

I have this PHP function that pulls/extracts data from xml elements and displays them on my webpage. However it is only working when used with a local path. not from any external sources. Here is the code.

Index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    include('render_xml_to_html.php');

    // The internal path. DOES work.
    render_xml_data('example.xml');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Example.xml

```
<eveapi version="2"><currentTime>2014-05-08 03:34:23</currentTime>
    <result>
        <serverOpen>True</serverOpen>
        <onlinePlayers>24957</onlinePlayers>
    </result>
    <cachedUntil>2014-05-08 03:35:58</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

The function - render_xml_to_html.php

```
<?php

function render_xml_data($path_to_xml_file){
        if (!file_exists($path_to_xml_file)){
            return;
        }else{
            $chars_to_replace = array('[\r]','[\n]','[\t]');
            $xmlstring = trim(preg_replace($chars_to_replace, '', file_get_contents($path_to_xml_file)));
        }
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
        foreach ($xml->result as $record) {
            echo '<div class="record">'."\n";
            echo '<h3>'.$record->onlinePlayers.'</h3>'."\n";
            echo '</div><!--end record-->'."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

The above code works as is. My issue is when I try to pull this info from the realtime .xml file on the hosts server. That url is:

https://api.eveonline.com/server/ServerStatus.xml.aspx/

When I replace example.xml with the above link it fails to work. So the following doe not work. Where I link to an external path rather than a local.

```
<?php
    include('render_xml_to_html.php');

    // The external path DOES NOT WORK
    render_xml_data('https://api.eveonline.com/server/ServerStatus.xml.aspx/');
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for this.

Comment: I looked into xslt but could  not figure it out. this is as close as I have got so far. Been at it alll day.

Comment: Look @ cURL or file_get_contents in PHP.

Comment: Follow some basic examples first. If you are familiar with them you can try to solve the particular problem.

Comment: ..............................edit

Comment: the way I have it setup is fine right now. It'll work just how i need it. I just need to know why it wont pull from an external source. thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `file_get_contents` on this one, it can get the job done. Consider this example:

```
$url = 'https://api.eveonline.com/server/ServerStatus.xml.aspx/';

// access the url and get that file
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

// convert it to an xml object
$contents = simplexml_load_string($contents);

echo "<div class='record'>Number of Online Players: ".$contents->result->onlinePlayers."</div>";
```

---

Sample Output:

> Number of Online Players: 23893

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I needed and so much easier. Thanks! What were you taking advantage of to get this done? I assume it has to do with the simplexml_load part.

Comment: Your welcome. I just thought, why not do it in a simple approach, first get the file of the respective url (using `file_get_contents`), then after getting it, convert the contents into xml object by using `simplexml_load_string`, so that you would be able to traverse it and get the desired data.